# Is it more secure to salt a string with a hash of itself?

Tags: vb.net, security, hash, string-hashing

So I've been looking at hashing passwords in vb.net and came across this thread (https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17421/how-to-store-salt/17435#17435) and it showed about the salt only increasing the time to make brute force attack if the salt is known to the intruder as they need to make a new rainbow table. Could this be made more secure by making the salt a hash of the plaintext?

As an example to hash "plaintext" but adding a salt the string, this salt then being a hash of "plaintext" making "32nfdw213123" as example then hashing the total "plaintext32nfdw213123". In this case the salt is different for every value used but when used for verification doing the same process to a correct check string should produce the same salt and therefore the same hash value and verify. Is this actually more secure?

Thanks

Comment: The salt should be random so that the same password for multiple users will produce multiple hashes.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: not really.

Longer answer:
Let's say some baddie has your database with all the passwords in it. He can now start brute-forcing passwords. Your goal is trying to make the brute-forcing as hard as possible.
So, theoretically, given that he has your database, he probably also knows how you're hashing your passwords (remember that security through obscurity is a bad form of defense). Your salts are no longer random, so our baddie can create a new rainbow table.